# MediaPlayer.create Exception

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I has this class that should play sounds.

```
public class AudioUtil {
    public static void play(Context ctx, File file) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, Uri.fromFile(file));
        try {
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But running give the following error:

```
12-19 14:02:56.070: I/MediaPlayer(4085): prepareAsync called in state 4
12-19 14:02:56.090: E/MediaPlayer(4085): error (1, -2147483648)
12-19 14:02:56.090: W/System.err(4085): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
12-19 14:02:56.090: W/System.err(4085):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
12-19 14:02:56.090: W/System.err(4085):     at br.com.digitalpages.renderer.util.AudioUtil.play(AudioUtil.java:13)
12-19 14:02:56.090: W/System.err(4085):     at br.com.digitalpages.renderer.view.infl.ViewInflater$3.execute(ViewInflater.java:146)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    player.setDataSource(ctx,  Uri.fromFile(file));
    player.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
player.start();
```